# Why do haemophillic females $X^hX^h$ die before birth?

Tags: human-biology, human-genetics, mutations

I just came across a statement in my book , while reading genetics, that haemophiliac females do not survive till birth (the reason not mentioned here why) . Before posting this question here I conducted quite a bit searching on the net but couldnt find any document on this. Can anyone tell me the reason why don't haemophiliac foetus make till birth ? I mean where is the problem, when a haemophiliac male having ***X<sup>h</sup>Y*** can survive why not an ***X<sup>h</sup>X<sup>h</sup>***  female ? [image]

Comment: What book are you referring to and can you include a quote?

Comment: Dinesh Objective Biology Vol III, ISBN 978-81-7608-229-7 Page no 261 , first paragraph 4th line

Comment: I have editedy question and attached the screenshot from the text

Comment: Please refer to a standard book on genetics. From [CDC website](http://www.cdc.gov/ncbddd/hemophilia/facts.html): *Females can also have hemophilia, but this is much rarer. In such cases both X chromosomes are affected or one is affected and the other is missing or inactive.  In these females, bleeding symptoms may be similar to males with hemophilia.*

Comment: This book is also trying to be too modest. Marriage between a carrier female and haemophiliac male it seems. Mating produces children, not marriage :P 

@DhrubaBanerjee I am from the same country and I never heard of this book. Always refer to standard books. And now since you have internet you can refer from authentic websites too.

Comment: Well, Dinesh Objective Biology is a revolutionary book amongst the community of PMT aspirants. Amyway, I didnt find anywhere in the website you quoted which mentions that "Haemophillic females survive. Its only talking about carrier females. Can you highlight for me please.

Comment: @DhrubaBanerjee Entrance exams have destroyed real education. Anyways this is not the right place to discuss such things. You can come to chat if you want. And I quoted the line verbatim from that website. Look carefully

Comment: How to join chat here ? I am new to this forum. I am more active in the chemistry forum.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21572/discussion-between-wysiwyg-and-dhruba-banerjee).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on an incorrect information.

Comment: Correcting misconceptions does not fall within the scope of this site? @WYSIWYG

Comment: @CRags Yeah I thought about it. And that's why answered the question.

Comment: I also think this question should remain open. It doesn't match any of the close reasons, is narrowly scoped and perfectly answerable. We address incorrect information all the time, that's one of the reasons this site is here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haemophiliac females are rare but they can survive just like affected males do. However, the case is slightly more complicated in women because of menstruation.

I could not find an article from any medical journal but [this](https://www.hemophilia.org/Community-Resources/Women-with-Bleeding-Disorders/Women-also-Bleed) site seems authentic enough for a reference.

Comment: Maybe there is some clinical cause which leads to bleeding like breaking if placenta.